# Disk formatting and permanent deletion of files

Tags: data-recovery, formatting

Does disk formatting cause permanent deletion of files or is it still possible to recover their content somehow?
Thank you for possible answers.

Comment: Define "formatting". There are several different procedures which are generically called formatting but they have substantial differences.

Comment: Such normal formatting using Windows

Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools

Computer Management - Storage - Disk Management

or DOS command.

Comment: "Quick formatting" or "full/deep formatting"?

Comment: I can remember such options like through the fog. But someone explained a little in this thread this difference. However "at least with consumer tools" in case of deep formatting is very disturbing.

Comment: The "at least with consumer tools" remark is just wrong. You cannot recover overwritten data no matter what. You can't, an intelligence agency can't as well.

Comment: But why multiple successive overwriting is used (up to 35 times) to permanently erase data, if one overwrite is enough in your opinion ?

Comment: it is not my opinion, I can provide multiple sources that say the same. Regarding your question: because there has been a research (subsequently disproven multiple times) that claimed to recover a couple of bits with a slight percentage of success. But military standards are based on the "err on the safe side" principle.

Comment: To be more precise: when I say a couple of bits I am really saying about 2 bits. Not even bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is still quite possible to recover a hard drive after it has been formatted. [Here](http://www.easeus.com/resource/format-file-recovery.htm) is just one tool for doing just that. Completely deleting all info from a hard drive involves overwriting successive garbage (usually FFFF) onto every sector. If you're never ever going to reuse the drive, removing the individual disks is an option. I've done that to every hard disk I've ever discarded.

Comment: Why `0xFF`? There is nothing special with that value.

Comment: I always assumed it was because FFFF ensures all cells in all sectors get some value written to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the question about Hard Drive Format Recovery
The answer is YES, even formatted the hard drive, we will still be able to recover the files back. Please note that it may not be a 100% recovery, I will try my best to tell you about the details on format recovery and how to get file back completely.

**Why We Can Get Files Back from Formatted Disk**

No matter deleting files or formatted the disk, the files will be marked as “deleted” and you will not see these files. Please note that all such files (data) are still on the hard disk (not erased).

What we should do is to scan the disk and find out all the files marked as “deleted”, and try to remove this mark.

You will have to do this as soon as possible before the “deleted” files are destroyed, yes, we can still get the “deleted” files back, but they are useless and not be able to open or read.

**Which Software Support Format Recovery Well**

According to the subject I will list some that support the Format Recovery technology. They would be the processional, simple and easy tools.

1 Hdata Recovery – Support format recovery; recycle bin recovery…and more, free trial

2 Recuva – Simple and easy enough, one of the processional tools.

3 Undelete 360 – Small but smart recovery tool, support flash disk recovery

4 iCare Format Recovery – Special for disk format recovery, compatible with different disk type

In fact, you really need not to try too many tools, if the recovery tool work it would help recover most of the files.

**How to Increase the Success Rate**

Below are 3 important tips for increasing our recovery success rate, please do follow the tips before recovering.

1 Stop using the hard drive and it would be better to turn off the power.

2 Do not install any new program in the partition where the file lost.

3 Save your files which have been recovered in a new external disk or flash disk.

Comment: You might want to mention that this applies to a quick format.  A low level format overwrites the contents, so recovery would not be possible, at least with consumer tools like these.

Comment: If you quick-format the disk the files are NOT marked as deleted. Only the first pieces of metadata in a partition are reinitialized.